# Function returning a UITableView causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, cocoapods

I am trying to make a function that returns a *UITableView* from a Cocoapod class. However, when I call the function, I get:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff89c111b0)

This does not happen when I initialize the table view within my main ViewController.

Eg

```
let tableView = UITableView()
```

This works correctly.

```
let tableView = laneScroller.makeTable()
```

However this fails.

Here is what my Cocoapod class does:

```
public class LaneScroller: NSObject {
    private var size: CGFloat
    public init(size: CGFloat) {
        self.size = size
    }

    public func makeView() -> UIView {
        return UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size))
    }

    public func makeTable() -> UITableView {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        return tableView
    }
}
```

I have implemented delegate and data source methods in extensions.

As you can see, I have used a similar approach to get a UIView and add it to my UIViewController's view and that works perfectly. I read somewhere that this might have something to do with weak and strong allocation. But not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you initialize lanescroller?

Comment: let laneScroller = LaneScroller(size: 100) @Chris

Comment: Can you show the full error?

Comment: Wait a minute I will add a screenshot.

Comment: Lanescroller is not a UiTableViewDelegate/datasource. The protocols are missing.

Comment: I have added them after the class definition as an extension. Didn't add here. Also, it's working now. I don't know what was wrong before.

Comment: What happens if you make `tableView` into a member of `LaneScroller` instead of a local var? (the error indicates you're trying to access a deleted object, so it may be a good idea to hold onto a reference.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove these two lines from function body

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

and add it where function returns tableView instance because you implemened tableView datasource and delegates in UiViewController extension and Lanescroller is not inherited from UIViewController or I can say that it's not a view controller.

Comment: I have added those extensions to laneScroller.